# transform web.config when publishing asp.net core webapi project in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I have app.config and app.Release.config. The transformation is working whe build the project from Visual Studio 2017 however no modification when hitting `Publish` to deploy the projectio to IIS

[image]

The app.config on publish folder has no transform data but the transformed value is on the web api.

Any idea where this tranformed value is stored?